# Store tomcat server configurations in the repository; is it a good idea?

Tags: tomcat, version-control, configuration, configuration-files

Here is the situation:
We have a big system composed of several tomcats, each one have (obviously) different configurations (server.xml, setenv.sh, catalina.properties, etc.) plus several environments were we deploy it for development, testing, acceptance, etc. with their own distinct configurations.

Currently all these configuration files only exists in their respective servers.
These servers are secured and with backups; no one can access them unless proper authorization has been granted.

However I still think this is not ideal:

- If we need to change some configuration we need a script to be executed by someone with authorization in the given server, for each server/environment this is annoying.
- Since we don´t have access to these configurations they might differ between environments which just seems like a source of problems.

So I think that putting all these configuration files under version control with the rest of the system´s code is a good way to fix the above issues and any change to those files can be easily deployed to each server/environment.

*However* this also have some issues:

- Some of the configuration files contain username and passwords; storing these in version control is a no-no.
- To add the credentials in the config files in a secure manner is somewhat complicated due to the restrictions we have.
- There are a *lot* of config files: 50+ due to the number of servers/environments; organizing them is not a trivial task.

My question(s):
Given all these issues; is it a good idea to store the configuration files in version control?
Should I leave the configuration files in their respective servers?
Should I separate the tomcat server-specific files (server.xml, etc.) from the application server-independent ones?
Is there another alternative I'm not seeing?

Sorry for the long question.